# how to update sub collection's all fields on V9 firebase in reactJs

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

so im creating instagram clone and in the firebase docs trying to update the fields:

```
 const uploadPostOnline = (imageUrl, caption) => {
  const userRef = doc(db, "users", "posts");
  setDoc(
    userRef,
    { imageUrl: imageUrl },
    { caption: caption },
    { likes: 0 },
    { likesByUsers: [] },
    { comments: [] },
    { createdAt: serverTimestamp() },
    {}
  );
};
```

this is my firebase database picture:
[image]

I want my code to create a collection of "post" for every user with the fields i added.

EDITED: This is the screenshot i got after adding  catch
[image: pic]

AGAIN EDITED: [image: USERID]

Again::: [image]

Security Rule Code:

```
       rules_version = '2';
     service cloud.firestore {
      match /databases/{database}/documents {
         function userIsAuthenticated(){
        return request.auth != null;
      }
       match /{path=**}/posts/{postId}{
        allow read, write : if userIsAuthenticated();
             }
        match /users/{userId}{
           allow read, write : if userIsAuthenticated();
        }
     }
      }
```

Answer (score 2):

> I want my code to create a collection of "post" for every user with
> the fields I added.

You need to use the ID of the user to add a `post` document in a subcollection, as follows:

```
  const userId = ...  // For example auth.currentUser.uid (check that value is not undefined, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user)
  const collectionRef = collection(db, "users", userId, "posts");
  addDoc(collectionRef, {
      imageUrl, 
      caption,
      likes: 0,
      likesByUsers: [],
      comments: [],
      createdAt: serverTimestamp()
    });
```

Comment: so it didnt work but i console.log the userId it did give me the id but also so many arrays of dataI have updated the answer please check the last screen shot

Comment: Do you have a security rules that prevent writing to the subcollection?

Comment: Ohh yes i think but i dont know what to do, i haave uploaded a screenshot please check it.

Answer (score 1):

The `setDoc()` takes a [DocumentReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.documentreference) as first parameter and a **single** object containing all the fields of your document as second. Try refactoring the code as shown below:

```
const uploadPostOnline = (imageUrl, caption) => {
  const userRef = doc(db, "users", "posts");
  setDoc(
    userRef, {
      // 'imageUrl: imageUrl' is redundant as your property name and var name are name
      imageUrl, 
      caption,
      likes: 0,
      likesByUsers: [],
      comments: [],
      createdAt: serverTimestamp()
    }
  );
};
```

Comment: sorry but it didnt work, on firebase it just dosent update at all

Comment: @MoeezMahmoodRamay can you try `setDoc(....).then(() => console.log("Updated")).catch(e => console.log(e))`? and then a screenshot of your console so we can see any errors that were loggeD?

Comment: i have updated my answer with the screen shot please check. 
It didnt find any errors and logged "Updated!"

Comment: @MoeezMahmoodRamay can you add a `.then(() => console.log("added")).catch(e => console.log(e))` block to your `addDoc()` statements and log any errors?